# Custom validator is being called multiple times

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, bean-validation

I have created a custom bean validator annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TestValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface ValidTest {
    String message() default "org.cdot.validations.ValidTest";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And its corresponding validator class

```
public class TestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTest, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTest annot) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String param, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
         System.out.println("[isValid] param : " + param);
         return param != null && param.trim().length() > 0;
    }
}
```

In my Bean I have a test method

```
@POST
@Path("validtest")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String testMethod(@ValidTest String param) {
    System.out.println("[testMethod] param : " + param);
    return "";
}
```

The issue is that when the EAR is deployed in Wildfly, and the API is called with parameter, `isValid` is being called three times. Whereas if the API is called with not parameter, the method is being called only once.

Can someone please help me on this?
Thanks